# How to strikethrough (a text) in Kate text editor?

Tags: kde, editors, kate

So,how can I strikethrough a text in kate or kwrite?

Comment: Li̶k̶e̶ t̶h̶a̶t̶?̶

Comment: Yes, like that exactly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a [markdown test](https://kate-editor.org/syntax/data/html/test.markdown.html): strikethrough must be `~~two tildes~~`